# LINQ to check if ID exists in List

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am using LINQ Entity framework.
I have a SQL table and I want to get all the items in the table that have an ID that exist in a List

Is this possible with LINQ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
(from item in yourContext.YourTable where yourList.Contains(item.ID) select item).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this work in EF now? See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/

Comment: That post is 3 years old. I believe it does now

Comment: @HarisHasan Hey, could you comment on the performance of this type of query versus creating a stored procedure that does an inner join against a table valued parameter?

Answer (score 17):

You can do this with `Contains` its translated into sql `IN`:

```
context.SomeTable.Where(r => someListOfId.Contains(r.ID));
```